# НЕ или НИ: Боюсь, что НИ/НЕ на какого [человека]

Tags: не-или-ни

Что следует использовать?

*На какого человека ты можешь повлиять прямо сейчас? Боюсь, что НИ/НЕ на какого.*

Answer (score 3):

Боюсь, что **ни** на какого

Серж уже ответил, добавлю  пояснение.

Боюсь, что ни на какого - это "боюсь, что (**не** можешь повлиять) **ни** на какого (человека)". А это классический пример усиления отрицания: частица НЕ перед глаголом передает отрицание, а частица НИ усиливает его.

Но это семантика, а вообще подобные  задачи решаются формально с учетом ударения, например:

Кто приехал? - **Ни**кто **не** приехал (усилительная **безударная** приставка НИ, усиление отрицания).

Приехал **не**кто N (отрицательная **ударная** приставка НЕ)

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае правильно: ни. Здесь ни усиливает отрицание.